# Github api - how to make authenticated requests?

Tags: node.js, authentication, basic-authentication, github-api

I am using Nodejs to write a simple web app that needs to read content from readme files using the GH api.

Everything works, but I am can't sort how to create requests as an authenticated user.

Sorry bit of a noob here :-) but is it not enough to add my client and secret key or an access_token as a parameter to my url? I have tried both and both seem to time out after 60 requests instead the 5000 the docs say.

I have looked at this site [Github Rate Limits](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) but I think I have done what it says.

Do I need to add a token on my server? Like how public and private ssh keys work? - Sorry, just trying to get an understanding of this.

Comment: Just note if you are running GitHub search requests you have to deal with a custom rate limit (30 per min usually).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me recently for getting a list of issues from Github. Nothing else set up on server or similar.

I used a token created with https://github.com/settings/tokens/new

```
const chalk = require("chalk");
const sa = require("superagent");
const { getProperty } = require("../context");

async function getIssues(org) {
  try {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/orgs/${org}/issues?state=open`;
    const apiToken = await getProperty("github.token");
    const res = await sa
      .get(url)
      .set("Authorization", `token ${apiToken}`)
      .send();
    res.body.forEach(issue => {
      console.log(issue.title);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

module.exports = getIssues;
```

Comment: Can I ask what your context file is like for this? I know you will obviously need to remove the token, but it seems like you have created a function in that file that you are calling?

Comment: sorry, I should have cut down that code a bit. The `getProperty` just returns the token I created in Github (that's a snippet out of a larger system), it's the '.set("Authorization", `token ${apiToken}`)' that is the important bit.